# mybatis update no effect

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I use mybatis-spring, springMVC,in my project, in one of my serviceImpl

```
public int setRetransmissionState(Map params) {
    String ids = (String) params.get("ids");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(ids.split(","));
    int result = 0;
    for (String id : list) {
        String retransmissionId = CreateOrderIDUtil.getUniqueKey("rt");
        params.put("sequenceId", id);
        params.put("retransmissionId", retransmissionId);
        int i = this.dao.setRetransmissionState(params);
        int j = this.dao.insertRetransmission(params);
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

DaoImpl

```
@Autowired
private SqlSession sqlSession;

@Override
public int setRetransmissionState(Map params) {
    return this.sqlSession.update("retransmission.setRetransmissionState", params);
}

@Override
public int insertRetransmission(Map params) {
    return this.sqlSession.insert("retransmission.insertRetransimssion", params);
}
```

Mapper.xml

```
<update id="setRetransmissionState" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
    UPDATE
        CS_APP_RELATION
    SET
        IS_RETRANSMISSION = '1',
        IS_RETRANSMITTING = '1',
        RETRANSMISSION_ID = #{retransmissionId}
    WHERE 
        SEQUENCE_ID = #{sequenceId}
</update>

<insert id="insertRetransimssion" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
    INSERT
    INTO
        CS_MODEL_RETRANSMISSION
        (
            RETRANSMISSION_ID,
            RETRANSMISSION_SOURCE,
            RETRANSMISSION_TARGET,
            OPERATOR_ID,
            RETRANSMISSION_TIME,
            RETRANSMISSION_SEQ,
            RETRANSMISSION_POSTSCRIPT,
            RETRANSMISSION_STATE,
            RETRANSMISSION_TYPE
        )
    VALUES
        (
            #{retransmissionId},
            '',
            #{targetId},
            #{operatorID},
            TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
            '',
            '',
            '0',
            '1'
        )
</insert>
```

what confused me is no matter how many the length of List , All the **insert** will success, but update effect only once and JVM doesnt throw any Exception
it tell my all goes well, what`s the issue ?

Comment: Do the entries with all of these sequenceIds exist?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz yes all the data in DB is right

Comment: Then what's i and j's value during these iterations?

Comment: I don't see much choice than to log everything into the console and see what queries really happen and how they should work...

Comment: try by adding sqlSession,commit() after update